# Mock Interface<T>

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

How does one mock/moq interface of T

```
  public interface IClient<T>
  {
    Task Call(Expression<Func<T, Task>> expression);
  }

  public interface IRepository {
    Task Get(int id);
  }
```

I'm trying to mock Call and Get expressions like so:

```
Mock<IClient<IRepository>> mock = new Mock<IClient<IRepository>>();

// Setup
mock.Setup(x => x.Call(s => s.Get(1))).ReturnsAsync(new Value());

// always returns null
var result = await mock.Object.Call(s => s.Get(1));
```

I am trying to test IRepository.Get() method. When I set it up by itself it does work. But when I wrap it within IClient the result is null.

Comment: Show what you are actually trying to test. So far the shown code is not testing what you think it is. It is simply calling the mock.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're trying to mock a generic interface; the problem is that the method you're trying to mock has a return type of `Task`, the asynchronous equivalent of `void`. It doesn't make sense for you to be trying to mock it to return a value.

What type are you expecting the `Call` method on your `IClient` interface to return?

Here I've adjusted your interface, adding an additional type parameter, `U`, for the return type of the `Call` method:

```
public interface IClient<T, U>
{
    Task<U> Call(Expression<Func<T, Task>> expression);
}
```

Then in the following unit test I've mocked this to return the integer `123`:

```
[Fact]
public async Task MockingAnAsynchronousMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IClient<IRepository, int>>();

    // Setup
    mock.Setup(x => x.Call(s => s.Get(1))).ReturnsAsync(123);

    var result = await mock.Object.Call(s => s.Get(1));
    Assert.Equal(123, result);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can not change 'IClient' interface. it's a third party lib. Please see my updated question